# Matrix norm inequality with norms less than one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, supremum-and-infimum, matrix-norms

We consider 2 different invertible matrices $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$, and a submultiplicative norm $\|.\|$ such that $\|A_{1}\|< 1$ and $\|A_{2}\|< 1$. My goal is to find:
$$
\sup\limits_{i_{1},i_{2},i_{3}i_{4}\in \mathbb N^{*}} \|A_{1}^{i_1}A_{2}^{i_2}A_{1}^{i_3}A_{2}^{i_4}\|
$$

My intuition says that the supremum is achieved when $i_{1}=i_{2}=i_{3}=i_{4}=1$. In the case of commuting $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$, it is easy to prove it, but when it not the case i don't know how to start, also i don't find a counter-example to disprove it. Does anyone can help?

Comment: $i_1$ and $i_4$ are definitely $1$ but not necessarily $i_2$ or $i_3$: just consider the $\mathbb R^2$ case when $A_2$ is (almost) the projection to the first coordinate line and $A_1$ is (almost) the rotation by $90$ degrees. Then $i_3=2$ is much better than $i_3=1$. In general you may have the maximizing $i_2$ and $i_3$ as large as you want (in the same example let $A_2$ be almost the rotation by fixed small angle).